# Windows - Issues Running turtle_tf2_py Package in ROS 2 Environment

Tags: windows, beginner-tutorials, windows10, win-ros, winros

I’ve encountered an issue while trying to run the launch_turtlesim_launch.py file in a ROS 2 environment. I received an error message stating: “package ‘turtle_tf2_py’ not found”. I attempted to install the turtle_tf2_py package from the source as per the instructions in this tutorial, but the turtle in the turtlesim simulator did not move as expected according to the tutorial.

I suspect there might be an issue with either the tutorial itself. I’m wondering if anyone has encountered a similar problem or could provide some solutions.

The tutorial mentions, ["Now let’s create a new `turtlesim_world_3_launch.py` file similar to `turtlesim_world_2_launch.py` to include one more `turtlesim_node` node."](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html#using-wildcards-in-yaml-files:%7E:text=Now%20let%E2%80%99s%20create%20a%20new%20turtlesim_world_3_launch.py%20file%20similar%20to%20turtlesim_world_2_launch.py%20to%20include%20one%20more%20turtlesim_node%20node.) As a beginner, I'm not entirely sure what "similar" entails in this context. I feel that the `turtlesim_world_3_launch.py` file could have a lot of code that could be shown to make things clearer.
And here was the `turtlesim_world_3_launch.py` code I used:

```py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
   config = os.path.join(
      get_package_share_directory('launch_tutorial'),
      'config',
      'turtlesim.yaml'
      )

   return LaunchDescription([
      Node(
         package='turtlesim',
         executable='turtlesim_node',
         namespace='turtlesim3',
         name='sim',
         parameters=[config]
      ),
      Node(
         package='turtlesim',
         executable='turtlesim_node',
         namespace='turtlesim3',
         name='sim',
         parameters=[config]
      )
   ])
```

But I cannot get the results mentioned in the tutorial.
Here was the screenshot of the issue,
[image]
, in which I found there is not a turtle who mimicked the behavior of another turtle.
I also hope someone could share the `turtlesim_world_3_launch.py` which can enable a successful running of the tutorial.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!